# There is no transition to another scene in Unity. There are no errors!

Tags: unity

I made a check in Unity for the presence of the value of the userID variable in the database. If yes, then we display the number of coins in the log. If not, we display in the log, they say, there is no such user and go to the registration stage. Here is the problem. There are no errors:

````
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Database1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string userID;
    
    void Start()
    {
        userID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
       FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(userID).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => { 
            if (task.IsFaulted) { 
                Debug.LogError("Error getting data from Firebase database"); 
                return; 
            } 
        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result; 
            if (snapshot.Exists) {
                if (snapshot.HasChild("coins")) { 
                    long pCoins = (long)snapshot.Child("coins").Value; 
                    Debug.Log("Value of coins: " + pCoins); 
                    // do something with pCoins variable 
                } else { 
                    Debug.Log("User does not have coins data"); 
                } 
            } else {
                Debug.Log("User does not exist in the database");
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }
});
    }
}
```
````

Comment: There are a lot of things in this code that could go wrong. Did you use the debugger of your IDE to check if the LoadScene line even gets executed?

Comment: I'm still a beginner. So could you elaborate on how to use debugging?

Comment: Not in only 600 characters and without even knowing which IDE you are using. The debugger is an essential tool for software development. Professional developers use it every day. Unfortunately it tends to get completely ignored in most game dev courses. But if you do your own research on the debugger of you IDE you will certainly find something.

Comment: IDE - Visual Studio Code

Comment: [You should have found this article on your own](https://unity.com/how-to/debugging-with-microsoft-visual-studio-code#debugging-using-vs-code)